# Queued builds failing: Microsoft.TypeScript.targets error: getting "unable to delete file, access to the path is denied"

Tags: msbuild, typescript

I have a solution in VS 2015, containing some Typescript files that I'm having some trouble with, the issue is when setting off a build (XAML build definition), a couple of minutes later the build falls over on deleting some js and map.js files in my project.

Not all of the Typescript files are causing me issues, some are fine, this is a subset of about five of them.

After searching around on the net I've tried the following:

- Setting max number of CPUs to 1
- Setting BuildInParallel to false
- Setting files/folders to not be read only
- Deleting the files from my project

This is where it gets really interesting as now the files have been deleted, I'm still getting the same error:

```
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets (177): Unable to delete file "Scripts\Models\languageSpoken.js". Access to the path 'D:\Builds\7350\<project>\CI (Octopus)\src\<project>\Scripts\Models\languageSpoken.js' is denied.
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem is usually caused by checking the JavaScript files into source control, and the build process not having access to those files.

Step one is to remove the JavaScript files from source control - they will be generated during the build.

You may also need to clean your build folder in case old files are hanging around. If you are hosting your own builds, you may want to actually delete those files to make sure they are gone - otherwise use the "Clean Build" option (you will need to make sure each build agent has a clean directory, so just running a single build with the clean option is not enough).